# Removing association from M:N relationship when deleting an entity

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

In my domain I have a many-to-many relationship. The problem is that GORM forces me to define owner entity but I don't think that either side "owns" the relation.

```
class User {    
    String username
    String password

    static hasMany = [organizations: Organization]
    static belongsTo = Organization

    static constraints = {
    }
}


class Organization {
    String name;

    static hasMany = [members: User]
}
```

In this case I'm obviously not allowed to delete User  who is in some organization (because Organization "owns" the relation). I would like to be able to delete both entities and on delete simply remove the relation (row from user_organization table). Is it possible or do I have to write this logic myself (if so, what would be the best way to implement this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to delete both sides of the relationship, no matter who is the "owner". The `belongsTo` just applies the proper cascading so you don't have to.

In your example if you want to delete a user you first have to remove the relationship. So, in order to delete a user you do:

```
organization.removeFromMembers(user)
user.delete()
```

And if you delete an organization, since it is the "owner", you just don't need to use `removeFrom*`.

Comment: Yes, I know about this. The right thing I'm looking for is probably combination of this and beforeDelete event.  Anyway I will accept your  answer, thx for advice.